# What is the difference between <T> and Tree<T> here? I am quite confused here

Tags: swift, generics

I don't quite understand when to state `Tree<T>` and when just `T`

```
class Tree<T> {
    var value: T

    private (set) var children: [Tree<T>] = []

    init(value: T) {
        self.value = value
    }
  
    func addChild(value: T) -> Tree<T> {
        let newChild = Tree<T>(value: value)
        children.append(newChild)
        return newChild
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<T>` makes `Tree` a generic type and declares the generic type parameter called `T`. If you want to declare a property as type `Tree`, you need to write it as `Tree<T>`. However, if you want to use the type of a tree node, then you need to use `T`.

When you declare `value`, you simply want to store the generic value, so its type needs to be `T`. However, the `children` array stores an array of trees, so you need to declare it as `[Tree<T>]`, not just `[T]`.

For each instance of `Tree`, the generic type parameter `T` might be different. By naming the generic type parameter something more meaningful, such as `Value`, this will become much more clear.

```
class Tree<Value> {
    var value: Value

    private (set) var children: [Tree<Value>] = []

    init(value: Value) {
        self.value = value
    }
  
    func addChild(value: Value) -> Tree<Value> {
        let newChild = Tree<Value>(value: value)
        children.append(newChild)
        return newChild
    }
}

let intTree = Tree(value: 1) // `Value` is of type `Int` here, but you don't need to specify it, the compiler can infer it
let stringTree = Tree(value: "value") // `Value` is of type `String` here
```

Comment: Ok, I understand what u said, but why can't I print out the staffs I add to the children? like when I state print(intTree.children) nothing is printed out.

Comment: @EDHENATION did you actually add any children to `intTree`? Also, this seems to be unrelated to your original question, so if you have a new problem, you should create a separate question for it.